# Making a ball curve in flight on rblx lua

Tags: lua, roblox

Ok im trying to find a way on roblox to script a ball that launches in the air using BodyVelocity but then instead of going streight down I want it to curve like do an arch then fall.

Answer (score 0):

ROBLOX physics simulations are... curious, to say the least. If you want to move in a perfect arc, your best bet is to just set the CFrame of the object directly. In order to calculate that, you'll need some physics knowledge. I recommend reading up about parabolic motion and CFrames before giving this a shot.

Comment: if you can't figure it out and need more help, just PM me (CoffeeFlux)

Comment: I don't appreciate the amount of mistrust this post puts into Roblox Physics capabilities. Roblox most definitely behave as expected for something as simple as making a ball move on an arc

Comment: in a proper arc? if you can get it to do that, please do provide a demo and answer the question yourself :)

Comment: I will answer if it's a programming puzzle. Putting two or three equations won't help OP at all. Instead, I will give references to truly help OP, rather than stating "oh the engine is curious..."